# Cant align image properly with internal css

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and wanted to get this picture to be a banner, and have text below it as a title, subtitle, etc., but when I use the code in the box, this happens. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOD15.jpg. I want that everything to be below that image of CS:GO GNDB png.

```
header {
background-image: url("images/header.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you're using for adding an image to the sets the header's background image to be your banner. You can see that it writes the text you want on top of it, which is why the property is called 'background-image'; the image is a background to something else. What you want is an image element that is its own discrete 'box' in the page, with nothing overlapping it or interfering. This is usually done with the "img" tag of HTML.

You can put a line in your HTML file that looks like:

```
<img src="images/header.png" />
```

To get the image by itself. See below for the documentation. There are also many tutorials for this kind of thing online.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have two options.

1. To give some padding-top to the header so the text will be displayed under the image. For example:

```css
header {
         background-image: url("http://www.jhakas.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/ad_720x90.png");
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-attachment: fixed;
         padding-top: 80px;}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header> 
      <h1>Some Title</h1>
      <h3>Some Subtitle</h3>
    </header>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

and after that to position the rest of the text in new div-s outside the header.

Or the second option is to add this banner image as an  element, which will display it as a block element in the header and you will be able to position the text under it without have this problem.